# Grab part of an URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, url

I have this link `viewdocument.php?a=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iesalfonsox.com%2Fimages%2FLIBROS_ESO_13-14.pdf` in (for example) `index.php` and I want to put only the URL of the document of the link.

Example:

Link: `http://www.myweb.com/viewdocument.php?a=some.pdf`

On the HTML: You're viewing "Some.pdf".

Do you understand? Convert "viewdocument.php?a=some.pdf" to "some.pdf".

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain what's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the current URL being accessed on your site, Php provide globals and you can access it using the `$_GET` variable:

so for your example you will use this:

```
$file = $_GET['a']; // will return some.pdf
```

The other case will be for parsing a url from a string, for which php provides a function:

[parse_url();](https://www.php.net/parse_url)

Follow the link to see examples

Comment: Do I put this code: `<?php $file = $_GET['a']; // will return some.pdf ?>` and `<html><body>&file</body></html>`?

Comment: `<body><?php echo $file ?></body>` should print it